# Enum USB devices in Linux/C++

Tags: c++, linux, usb

Im writing IO routines for a linux device that will have various and changing USB devices connected to it. To this end I need to be able to figure out which device is connected to which port so I can open it with the correct software. Something akin to 'udevinfo' would be ideal but I have no idea how to start in writing such.

Suggestions on c++ apis to read?

Comment: I agree with 341008. One vote up to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a BASH solution in the chkconfig file. I walk through all ttyUSB entries and look at the driver info for each:

```
USB_ID=`egrep -i "mct u232|pl2303|keyspan" -m 1 /proc/tty/driver/usbserial | awk '{ printf( "$d", $1 )}'`
if [ -z $USB_ID ]
then
   echo $echo_n "No USB serial adapter found.";
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [libudev++](http://danielkitta.org/doc/libudev++1/reference/html/index.html). It seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: libudev++ looks very interesting but doesn't want to install on my RHEL5.5 system.

Answer (score 2):

See [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/)'s `libusb_get_device_list`, `libusb_get_bus_number`, `libusb_get_device_address`.

Answer (score 2):

[GIO](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.25/) should help you in that. Connecting to the [volume-added](http://library.gnome.org/devel//gio/2.18/GVolumeMonitor.html#GVolumeMonitor-volume-added) and [volume-removed](http://library.gnome.org/devel//gio/2.18/GVolumeMonitor.html#GVolumeMonitor-volume-removed) signals will alert your program to any storage device added or removed from the system. If you do not need the level of control provided by GIO, you can use [libudev++](http://danielkitta.org/doc/libudev++1/reference/html/index.html) which provided a high level wrapper over GIO.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what kind of information you need, but you could just go through /sys/bus/usb?

Comment: The trick for me is figuring out which USB device corresponds to which entry in /dev/TTYUSBn. I haven't had much success with libusb or libudev so Im thinking more about a scripted solution that would pass in the relevant dev path on the cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

More recent solution:

Iterate over these file system directories:

```
/dev/serial/by-id
/dev/snd/by-id
/dev/disk/by-id
/dev/input/by-id
/dev/v4l/by-id
```

depending on what device class you are looking for.

For example, finding the serial port for my Arduino Nano:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

const std::string path = "/dev/serial/by-id";

for( const auto & file : std::filesystem::directory_iterator( path ) )
{
    const std::string s = "NANO_33_IoT";
    if( file.path().generic_string().find(s) )
    {
        return file.path();
    }
}
```