# Linux: getting camera device number

Tags: c++, linux, camera

I have: Linux laptop with built-in camera, 2 other cameras, OpenCV-based program.

I need: to pass the device number of those two cameras to the program automatically.

In OpenCV you open a camera with `videoCapture.open(n);`, where `videoCapture` is an object of a `cv::VideoCapture` and `n` is device number of the camera you wish to open. My program uses two webcams. Here OpenCV part of this question is over.

Usually this `n` is hard-coded or manually passed by user. I want to write a script that would automatically detect the device number of two desired cameras. But built-in camera is the obstacle.

When loaded, Linux defaults the device number of the built-in camera to `0`. Two connected USB-cameras get the numbers `1` and `2` accordingly. And when you reboot the laptop you most probably get all the numbers mixed up, e.g. built-in camera - `1`, `0` and `2` - for USB-cameras. And anyways I have to change the device numbers in the code when I switch the platfrom and execute the program on desktop which have no built-in cameras.

I thought I could write sh script that would parse an output of `lsusb | grep Logitech` (those two USB webcams are Logitech ones) and get the device number according to USB Bus number but that rebooting thing obstructs this.

I would appreciate any ideas and thoughts on what I could check out for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enumerate the USB devices--you can see details on how to do it here: 
[Enum USB devices in Linux/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608791/enum-usb-devices-in-linux-c)

For a previous question similar to yours, see: [How to count cameras in OpenCV 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322939/how-to-count-cameras-in-opencv-2-3)